# Manhwa about a female lead who was a villainess, but was reincarnated in another world, where she became friends with the male lead's sister

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I don’t remember much, but I hope you can help me. I’m searching for a Manhwa where the female lead (FL) is reincarnated. She was a villainess in her first life and was actually from another world, I guess.

She is friends now with the male lead's sister; something happens at a ball and the FL wishes that the sister will dance with a flirty guy. (It is saying that the sister never dances and it shows that the flirting guy likes the sister).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Also, what colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: If she was a villainess, was she aware she was living in a fictional story, or simply a "wicked woman"? Was she a villainess in her next life as well? Do you remember how she died as a villainess, e.g. was she executed for something?

Comment: @qazmlpok I think the term "villainess" is frequently used in the titles of isekai manga. I don't know if the "villainess" actually is always evil - the "first life" in this context may be another story in which they conflicted with the protagonist. Or in which all the characters assumed she had done something evil, because the author wrote that she had.

Answer (score 2):

I think the story might be ***[I Have Become the Heroes' Rival](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/odnarb0/your-ultimate-love-rival)***...?

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/your-ultimate-love-rival):

> Naturally charming, Irene attracts women like a magnet, even when she doesn't mean to. Enter her best friend, Claudia, who refuses to marry any of her three suitors because of her affection for Irene. As a result, these powerful and mentally unstable men declare Irene as their rival in love and threaten her life. She knows none of them deserve to be with Claudia, but she doesn’t want to die! To save both her friend and herself, Irene must prove she's their ultimate rival, but will she succeed?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct manhwa, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.